# Upload Image using wp_insert_attachment and file url don't have file extension

Tags: images, uploads

I need to upload an image using

```
$filename = 'www.domainname.com/images/12345';
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

$attachment     = array(
    'guid'           => basename( $filename ),
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
);

$attach_id   = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename , $parent_post_id );

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

But here the file name don't have any extension.
How should I proceed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your `$filetype` return? Did you save this file locally?

Comment: It is returning array with key "ext" => false and "type" => false;

Comment: Try checking with the PHP function `exif_imagetype()`

Comment: Tried with it, it is returning me 2 i.e it is JPEG image.

Comment: Unrelated: second argument for `wp_insert_attachment` should be an absolute path ([doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)).